# how use command line "updater" in android

Tags: android

i have problem with android, please tell me how use command line "updater" in

```
/system/bin/
```

i do:

```
cd <sdk-android-home>/platform-tools/
./adb shell
# cd /system/bin
# ls up*
updater
#
```

i search and read code of it in [here](https://www.assembla.com/code/android-gb-for-sharp-is01/git/nodes/bootable/recovery/updater/updater.c?rev=7a5dc628b257a45e0657359badd43284909ba629) but i can't understand it or argument of command.
i hope everybody help me.
thanks.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

This binary is intended for use in recovery mode. It typically shouldn't even be present in the normal system partition, but I know it is present there on some devices unfortunately. In short, unless you're doing something extremely advanced, you should never run this executable.

Comment: thanks u repy :), i want to build a version froyo and want to understand update mechanism of its. example, my froyo version have error, i can update patch version with command line "updater", thanks.